# Mount External HFS+ to Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, mount, hfs+

I recently got a Win8 Laptop to replace my broken MacBook.  I have an external enclosure for my macbook harddrive and would like to mount it as a file system on my windows laptop to move files. I installed HFSExplorer but it won't recognize the usb connected drive. In fact, Windows sees a "USB-Serial ATA" adatper but won't mount the drive.
Does anyone know how to mount and read the old mac harddrive on win8? I just want to move photos and such to my new computer.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the program to load device, then choose the auto option

**File** -> **Load Filesystem from Device...** -> **Autodetect** -> <kbd>OK</kbd>

I have done this without using the Administrator mode, but your mileage may vary

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned I did that. it only sees partition 1and 2 which are the windows partitions . the drive is also not visible in the win explorer, only as a USB to serial ata adapter

Comment: It won't be visible in Windows explorer, that's why you have the hfs explorer. It worked on every other Mac drive, by lo ading it up, selecting the first menu, then first menu option and clicking ok. On my cell so I can't post better instructions for about an hour

Comment: Alright I got it. The trick was to run it as an administrator (even though the account already is an admin). Without admin privileges it wouldn't recognize the attached USB drive.